# How to save pandas to_csv from left to right?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Pandas to.csv() function saves my table from right to left, like in hebrew even thought the dataframe is in English.

I have the indexes on the right and columns going right to left, how can I do the opposite?

[image: The csv table i got]

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the order of your columns, and store it again as a `csv`.

Method 1: `attribute.columns[::-1]` on the corresponding dataframe:

```
df[df.columns[::-1]].to.csv()
```

Method 2:

```
df.iloc[:, ::-1].to_csv()
```

### Both yield the same result.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help!. both option dosent work and saves the same thing, is there any place to configure rtl or ltr in the to_csv() function?

Comment: Can you please try again and make sure you are saving it correctly? I have tested it on my computer and it stores them as CSV's in the opposite column order as you wish.

Comment: No there is no built in way for the ```to_csv``` function to do it. Can you do ```df.to_csv('name1.csv')``` , and ```df.iloc[:, ::-1].to_csv('name2.csv')``` and check the two csv's?

Comment: i deleted the excel file and used the lines in your answer, still the same matrix,  i manged to fix it inside excel, by changing the settings to ltr to all excel files, still searching for a way to make it use ltr only on specific files

Comment: It works well on mine. I have attached a picture in case you want to see. What pandas version are you using? ```print(pd.__version__)```

Comment: Is the dataframe you want to save called ```df```? How is your dataframe called?

Comment: 1.3.5 , all the options work for me if i change my excel setting to ltr globaly so probably thats why it works for you. i guess il change my excel settings to ltr if i work on english spreadsheets and rtl otherwise, thank you anyway

Comment: Okay i didn’t know about the global setting in excel. So thanks for the tip.